# Links to Resources for Developing WPF Touch and Mouse-controlled apps WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

I am looking to develop an app which can be operated by touch (Microsoft Surface) or using a regular laptop with Mouse. Is this possible, and if so, how do I go about implementing it?

Resources/Links/Blogs much appreciated--thanks in advance!

Link to similar/unanswered question: [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11085078/1076406)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET 4.0+ controls support both Touch and Mouse input methods.  For example, Click events are still fired by using Touch. There are also touch-specific events like TouchDown, TouchUp, etc.

You can import the Microsoft Surface 2.0 SDK and use the controls they've bundled.  I particularly like their SurfaceListBox since it seems to handle touch-scrolling the better than a traditional listbox.  *Technical note:* if you import the Surface SDK libraries, your target machine **must** have the Surface redistributable installed.  It registers vital DLLs to your system, which you can do manually through COM Interop if that works for your project.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Erode. Will 4.0 be compatible with Blend 4 and Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: @Rachael Yes, 4.0 is the last compatible with 2010-era products.  If you want to utilize C# 5 and its async/await features you need to move to .NET 4.5 which requires VS 2012 (great, in my opinion).

Comment: Thanks, again! You've been very helpful. I wish you had a blog to follow! I've been looking for a straight forward opinion on VS 2012.

Comment: @Rachael No problem, perhaps if I ever get around to starting a blog, I'll *comment-reply* it your way.